# .NET Framework - WPF application does not running

Tags: .net, mysql

I have a WPF Application running on .NET Framework 3.0. I have run the application on a PC with the OS: Windows XP Professional version 2002 Service pack 3 and includes the required framework.

The application starts and runs fine but I am unable to log in with a Username/Password which works on the other PC.

The database being used to perform authentication is located on the other PC and is a MySQL database.

Comment: This seems to indicate the problem is not to do with WPF, but with the authorization logic. Are your credentials checked against a database? If so, make sure you can access the database from the PC it's failing for.

Comment: Hi Lukazoid, Thanks for reply...Authorization logic problem is not there. I have trying with same password and user name on another PC .. It is working fine. Also pinged database server, that gives me access of shareble folder also. So not a network problem is there. Are you feeling that there is any hardware or OS related issue?

Comment: Ok, perhaps not the logic, but it indicates that one PC is able to do something, while the other PC is not. This could be an inability to access the database to perform the log in.

Comment: Database is on other PC and in MySql ..so any way or want to install anything that makes it enable to access the My Sql?

Comment: You will need to enable remote access, here's how: [guide](http://richbui.com/2009/03/06/how-to-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-server-on-windows-server/) You may also need to add port 3306 to the windows firewall exception.

Comment: thanks a lot Lukazoid... i have a solution after your comments..It's a great trick for my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like leaving an 'unanswered' question, plus the reputation is nice, so here is my answer from comments.

Enable remote access to the MySQL database, here is a [guide](http://richbui.com/2009/03/06/how-to-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-server-on-windows-server/). You may also need to add port 3306 to the windows firewall exceptions.